# Linq query with join and where not equals

Tags: linq, join

I have three tables named 'User', 'User_Right' and 'Right' respectively.
A user is assigned rights by using the 'User_Right' table as a linking table between the 'User' and 'Right' tables.

I want to get a list of the rights that are not currently assigned to a specific user.
The specific user is identified by his ID and is used as a parameter called 'userid' in my query.

My query looks like this so far.

```
var searchresults = (from ur in context.User_Right 
                             join r in context.Right on ur.Right_ID equals r.Right_ID 
                             where ur.User_ID.Equals(userid) 
                             select r.Right_Name).ToList();
```

This returns all the rights the user currently has assigned.
How can I get the ones the user does not have assigned yet?

Comment: can you give these three tables structure, so that can be guided more well

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
  var  searchresults = (from ur in context.User_Right 
                        join r in context.Right on ur.Right_ID equals r.Right_ID 
                        where ur.User_ID == userid) 
                        select r.Right_Name,r.Right_ID).ToList();


    db.Right.Where(x=> !searchresults.Contains(x.Right_ID))
```

or this:

```
  var  searchresults = (from ur in context.User_Right 
                        join r in context.Right on ur.Right_ID equals r.Right_ID 
                        where ur.User_ID != userid) 
                        select r.Right_Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is an appropriate relationship between the two tables, use **Association/Navigation Properties** instead of joining. Your query should like similar to:

```
var searchresults = (from ur in context.User_Right 
                     where ur.User_ID.Equals(userid) 
                     select ur.Right.Right_Name).ToList();
```

You can see how neater and simpler this query is. Perhaps in your code, the property `ur.Right` has a different name, but you get the idea.

As for your question, try this:

```
var other_rights = (from r in context.Right 
                    where !r.UserRight.User_ID.Equals(userid) 
                    select r.Right_Name).ToList();
```

Again, perhaps in your code, the property `r.UserRight` has a different name, but you get the idea.

Side note: Following C# naming conventions and removing the underscores from your entity names makes your code read better.